# Check prolog palindrome 123123

Tags: prolog, palindrome

Check that my list is an palindrome. If it is, i have to increase every second element in my list.

```
palindrome(L) :-
        reverse(L, L).
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with "*i have to increase every second element in my list*"? What did you try to solve that problem?

Comment: 1.if my list is a palindrome, my programm have to inc every %2 element in my list.

Comment: 2. I`m trying to div my list leght on 2 and thats waht i did.

Comment: So given `[1,2,3,3,2,1]` is a palin drome, it has to unify a variable with `[1,3,3,4,2,2]`?

Comment: What pattern(s) do you think you need?

Comment: Yes. i can`t get every element in my list like it is in every functional language(list[1]).

Comment: You've got a condition that establishes a palindrome. You just need to write predicate that processes every 2nd element. Hint: consider a recursive predicate, `increment_2nds([A,B|T], [A,C|S]) :-...`. Don't forget the base case.

Comment: @Doomed_: did you already implement some list processing functions? Perhaps it might help to look at some, and try to implement some simpeler ones first.

Comment: if my version about palinrome check is right, so why i`ve got an exeption "Undeclarated identifier 'reverse/2'?

Comment: What prolog are you using? `reverse/2` is pre-defined in gnu and SWI Prologs.